# Docker - No such file or directory. Copy does not copy all files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Dockerfile does not completely copy all files from the local directory.
I don’t understand why he copies the folder from the backend, but it doesn’t have all the files.
Thanks for help..

structure:

```
docker/
    django/
          /Dockerfile
          /backend/
              requirements.txt
              src/
    angular4/
          /Dockerfile
          /client
    docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    hostname: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: alinta
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  backend:
    build: ./django
    image: alinta
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/alinta/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  migration:
    image: alinta
    command: python3 manage.py migrate --noinput
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/alinta/
    depends_on:
      - db
  frontend:
    build: ./angular4
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/alinta
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
```

Dockerfile (django):

```
FROM postgres:9.6
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-contrib-9.6 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common 
#RUN echo postgres:postgres | chpasswd
#RUN pg_createcluster 9.6 main --start
#RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start

FROM python:3.7
MAINTAINER Nikita Alekseev <nik_alekseev@outlook.com>
# Alinta
# Version: 1.0
# Install Python and Package Libraries
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
RUN apt-get install -y \
    libffi-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    net-tools \
    vim
RUN apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip \
    python3-dev \
    python3-virtualenv \ 
    libpq-dev \ 
    postgresql \
    postgresql-contrib \
    nginx \
    curl
RUN pip3 install virtualenv
# Project Files and Settings
ARG PROJECT=alinta
ARG PROJECT_DIR=/var/www/${PROJECT}
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR/backend/src
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR/backend/src/static
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR/backend/src/media

#WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR
COPY ./backend /var/www/alinta/
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR/backend
RUN virtualenv -p python3.7 --no-site-packages env
RUN /bin/bash -c "source env/bin/activate"
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR/backend/src
EXPOSE 8000
```

`docker-compose build` 
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'

Comment: Can you provide the full output of the command?

Comment: I would like to help you solve the issue but I also have to warn you that this issue is the least of your problems. You use a postgres image to start with and then on the second line you install postgres. Then you install it again down below... Along with nginx and vim and others that aurely don't belong there. In docker-compose you mount the same to all services in same location - should not need to do this

Comment: @Mihai Thanks! I removed the postgres loading and split the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

For your **Dockerfile** your requirements.txt is in backend directory, and not on the same level, so adding or copying it will make it visible:

so add:

```
ADD ./backend/requirements.txt requirements.txt
```

or

```
COPY ./backend/requirements.txt requirements.txt
```

before you run

```
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Just copying backend directory as:

```
COPY ./backend /var/www/alinta/
```

will not allow Docker to know the context of your **requrements.txt**. Using `ADD` or `COPY` will instruct Docker how to locate file.

Comment: I think this command does instruct Docker about where to run the command and find the file:. WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR/backend. Did you miss this line or you don't agree?

Comment: I think that whole setup is inconsistent and needs to be refactored. Having multiple WORKDIR statements is risky. Much better is having `ARG` or  `ENV` at the top, then `COPY` or `ADD`, and then `RUN` and `WORKDIR` in the end.

Comment: Having multiple FROM statements will generate error, and Postgres is already in docker-compose, so this whole top part is not needed in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Also, you have `FROM python:3.7` - you probably need an image that will have both python 3.7 and ubuntu or other debian.

Comment: @dmitryro Thanks for the answer! But what to do if the source of the project (src) lies in this folder. And there are a lot of files. Do not add them all through COPY?

Comment: @dmitryro How then to properly load the finished project in Docker?

Comment: @fill For each project, used by **docker-compose** you *may want* to have a separate **Dockerfile**, so place your **Dockerfile** where your project `WORKDIR` is going to be, specify it in       `context: ./your_dockerfile_dir`
 and  `dockerfile: YourDockerfile` in your **docker-compose.yml** and then make sure the layout of this directory is such that everything, that is not in the same `yor_docker_dir`, made available via `COPY . .` or `COPY ./dir_before dir_after`

Comment: @dmitryro In this case, I will get a lot of instructions COPY. There are a lot of files in the Django project. Do I need to write a COPY instruction for each file? Is it really impossible to recursively load a project into a container?
For the first time I work with a docker I apologize for possible stupid questions.

Comment: You don't need copy as long as the file you're going to use is either at the same level (context) where your particular **Dockerfile** is located, or you explicitly specify the relative path to it. The easiest for you would be isolate all your Django project in one directory, dedicate a **Dockerfile** to it, and then specify that context and **Dockerfile** in your **docker-compose.yml**